# migration to jboss wildfly

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly

i try to migrate my app from jonas to JBoss WildFly 8. I'm facing the following error:

```
14:30:49,518 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."myAppEar.ear/myAppMetier.jar#myApp": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."myAppEar.ear/myAppMetier.jar#myApp": java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
   at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)
   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.rebind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:120)
   at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.rebind(NamingContext.java:274)
   at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:269)
   at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:431) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
   at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:431) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
   at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.bind(NamingHelper.java:97) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(SessionFactoryObjectFactory.java:113) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:367) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:318) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$1100(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:67) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
   ... 8 more
```

I configure wildfly to use hibernate 3.6 in the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="myApp" transaction-type="JTA">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <jta-data-source>nfsbdd</jta-data-source>

         <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

         <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
                <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
                <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:3"/>
         </properties>

   </persistence-unit>
```

The application run with hibernate3.6, ejb3.0, jsf 2.1.  Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your hibernate 3.6 conflicts with hibernate 4.3.8 from wildfly. If you are not using hibernate specified annotations and functions, would be better to migrate to JPA. Good solution, but not perfect, is migrate to hibernate 4.3.8. What variant is less painfull, depends on your application code and architecture.

Comment: Sorry i haven't mark the question as resolve. It work great. The problem was a silent catch make by another dev. It's not the hibernate fault